# Gamemaker studio 2 getting error message

Tags: game-maker

I'm currently using gamemaker studio 2 following a youtube guide on making my first game. I am very new to coding and need some help.

Im getting this error message attached to my code and I'm not sure why.

[image]

Comment: Can we assume this persists after saving?

Comment: Use double quote `"` instead single `'`: `dash_key = keyboard_check_pressed(ord("C"));`

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
dash_key = keyboard_check_pressed(ord("C"));
```

Note the double quotes ( **"** ) instead of single quotes ( **'** ). If done correctly the `"C"` should be yellow in the editor to signify that a `string` is present.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the engine thinks there are 0 arguments instead of 1. Furthermore, ord is a function that takes in a character, not a string.